# Missing space on raid drive

Tags: raid, disk-usage

I have raid drive in Ubuntu 22.04 created from 4 drives in raid-0.
It is formatted with ext4 and mounted to `/mnt/md1`. When I do `df -h` is see that drive in output, but it shows also, that 692 GB out of 3.7 TB is used. When I try to list that content to find out what is taking almost 700 GB with `ls -alh` command, it shows nothing

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           9,5G  3,3M  9,5G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       110G   71G   34G  68% /
tmpfs            48G     0   48G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       240M  6,1M  234M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           9,5G  172K  9,5G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/md0        1,8T  954G  787G  55% /mnt/md0
/dev/md1        3,7T  692G  2,8T  20% /mnt/md1
```

```
ls -alh /mnt/md1

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4,0K aug 22 08:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K aug  3 16:09 ../
drwx------ 5 root root 4,0K aug 22 08:49 lost+found/
```

I don't understand it. How can I find out whats that missing space is holding and free that space ?

I tried also:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/md1 | grep "Block size"

dumpe2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Block size:               4096
```

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/md1 | grep "Reserved block count"

Reserved block count:     49710585
```

I set the reserved size to 1%

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/md1

tune2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 1% (9942117 blocks)
```

```
sudo du -h --apparent-size /dev/md1

0   /dev/md1
```

I am out of ideas for now.